# Problem plotting scatter plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am trying to plot a simple scatter plot to show the relationship between two columns in the 'mtcars' dataset. No errors were received on execution, and the `ggplot2` library was loaded successfully. I expected a plot for the given code:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(
  data = mtcars,
  mapping = aes(x = hp, y = mpg)
) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: The plot is not created when you source the file. Put the cursor on the first line of your code (`library(ggplot2)`) and press Ctrl + Enter twice.

Comment: You can also click on "Run" button in RStudio

Comment: I tried that before querying.